# A question on an infinite linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables

Let  $0<q <1.$ We denote by $\psi(q;z)$ the Euler function, that is, $$\psi(q;z)=\prod_{j=0}^\infty \left(1+q^j z\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{q^{k(k-1)/2}z^k}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\dots(1-q^k)}.$$

Also, let $\{c_k\}_{k\geqslant 0}$ be a sequence such that $c_0=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}c_k=0.$

Assume that
\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k\cdot \frac{q^{k(k-1)/2}z^k}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\dots(1-q^k)}\\
=
\psi(q^2; qz)\cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_{2k}\cdot \frac{q^{k(k-1)}z^k}{(1-q^2)(1-q^4)\dots(1-q^{2k})}.\end{align}

**Question**. Does it follow that all  $c_k=0$?

Comment: Consider the smallest $k$ with $c_k\neq 0$ and compare the coefficients of $z^k$...

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand. Assume that c_1 is different from 0. How can it be guaranteed that the coefficients obtained from equating those in right and left sides tend to 0?

Comment: @Deepti As, $c_0=0$, the r.h.s has $z^2$ as minimum power of $z$. So, $c_1=0$ and by induction all $c_k=0$.

Comment: The RHS is: $(1+qz)(1+q^3z)...\left(\frac{c_2z}{1-q^2}+\dots \right)=\frac{c_2}{1-q^2}z+\dots$.

That is, $c_2= c_1(1+q).$ And $c_1\neq 0$ in general.

Comment: @Deepti Sorry, I saw it wrong.

Comment: No worries!   Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Little rearrangement gives, $$c_{2n}=[c_{n}q^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+q^{-k})-\sum_{\substack{k+l=n \\ k,l>0}} q^kf_k(q^2)f_l(q^2)c_{2l}$$, where $f_k(q)=(q^k\prod_{m=1}^{k} (q^{-m}-1))^{-1}$. It seems that the first term of r.h.s dominates and $c_{2n}$ increases with $n$ if $c_k$s aren't 0.

Comment: @Alapan Das Could you please provide more details? because the sum in the RHS also includes c_n and I cannot understand how it may be concluded that this term dominates the whole sum.